# Smart deployment tools for Java

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a tool able to deploy partial webapps, not just deploying a war containing a whole new version of a webapp. The purpose is to permit automated deployment (for example, but not only, properties files) in a Mavenized environment. Any idea?

Comment: It's called [_exploded deployment._](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+%22exploded+deployment%22) You deploy a folder instead of a [J|W|E]AR, which means you can update individual files in the folder instead of the whole archive. What container/app server are you using?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know the expression. Do you know any tool to automate the process?

Comment: http://blog.teamextension.com/hot-deployment-of-java-web-applications-in-eclipse-439 <-- This page explains using an exploded WAR through Eclipse and Tomcat

Comment: Again, it would be helpful if you could tell us which specific Java technologies you're using.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat and JBoss, with Spring.

Comment: +1 for linkedin Glu. You can rely on that And -1 for ControlTier. that is too much to integerate and to perform any function and personally i believe it's a bit more complicated. I left controlTier after using it for 1 month and now i am working on Linekdin Glu.
Give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kwatee (http://www.kwatee.net) can do both war or exploded deployments. It has a web user interface but you can automate it via python CLIs or a supplied ant task.

Answer (score 4):

http://liverebel.com - Take a look on LiveRebel. I think that is what you need.

Comment: As for exploded deployment, you can use LiveRebel CLI "upload" command  (followed by "deploy" or "update") and direct it at a directory instead of a WAR/EAR file. LiveRebel will do an automatic diff and upload just the changed resources. http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/liverebel/reference/cli.html

Comment: Also, LiveRebel can manage those properties files for you, see http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/liverebel-2-6-sneak-peek-environment-configuration-management/ for more details.

Comment: It seems LiveRebel is discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

I have found some tools, too:

- [Glu](https://github.com/linkedin/glu), which is maintained by the LinkedIn team
- [ControlTier](http://doc36.controltier.org/wiki/Main_Page), which seems able to do that and much, much more
- [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home), which is a Java framework if you want to write your own deployment tool (which is not my case, but could be interesting for somebody else)

Comment: Is there any document for converting the application(currently deployed using RPM) to glu?

Comment: The new URL of Glu: http://pongasoft.github.io/

Comment: ControlTier is a dormant project, now. You can find what's left of it here: https://github.com/gschueler/controltier-wiki

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the [maven wagon plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) to do this. Try the `wagon:upload-single` goal - I think it is what you are looking for, you just need to fill in the configuration blanks so to speak.

One gotcha to remember - you need to add the server configuration to your maven settings.xml file, which is pretty easy to do, just don't forget it.